# Is there any ROM for HuaWei U8800+/U8800pro

Tags: ubuntu-touch

i am very excited that ubuntu has published a cellphone ROM, but it seems only avaiable on Galaxy Nexus && Nexus, i do not have these kind of phone, only a HuaWei U8800+/U8800pro is avaiable, So i want to ask if the ROM is avaiable for HuaWei, or How long will this ROM be avaiable for this device? Thanks a lot!!